# Increasing points of accepted answer by a factor of upvotes of question

Tags: feature-request

I am wondering why the accepted answers of questions with positive upvotes don't receive extra points by the number of the upvotes that a question gets itself, at least for the case that upvoters of question are differing from upvoters of the anwrer.

Just to clarify, I have been always the asking person and so this does not directly benefit me.

Comment: The answerer *already* benefits from extra attention to popular questions. What would extra points (beyond the +15 accepted answer bonus) get them? Why complicate the scoring?

Comment: Maybe you are right, that the inherent feedback system results in high-voted questions to reward the answerers with more votes. Its mere 15 points didn't seem to be to be enough to appreciate. I thought maybe rather than increasing the score for acceptance, to add extra points for answerer by the upvotes of the question.

Comment: You already have an option to reward the accepted answer: give them a bounty. There is an explicit 'award existing answer' option, and it'd let you share some of the wealth earned from question upvotes.

Comment: I don't see the reason that I have to share my points with them. Are we really afraid of inflation?? :)

But anyways  I wasn't aware of "award existing answer" option!

Comment: As for rewarding people that spend time answering: answer upvotes are worth twice a question upvote. An upvote on a question is +5 in reputation, vs. +10 for an answer.

Comment: I think I knew the latter. I just had the feeling of under-appreciation. Thanks for explaining anyway.

Comment: What problem is this designed to solve?  Are highly upvoted questions currently not attracting enough attention from answerers?  That'd be the only reason I could see to want to do this, and I see no evidence that highly upvoted questions are currently not getting enough attention.

Answer (score 4):

Folks have left some good comments already that I agree with, but here are my two biggest issues:

1. What correlation is there between the quality a highly-upvoted question and the accepted answer, thereof? There's absolutely no guarantee that there is any significant relation. And, so...
2. If people have voted for the question, but not the answer; that was their choice, or lack of seeing the answer. In the meantime, others will see the answer and be able to vote on it. (And besides; answers tend to get more votes than questions).

This puts too much weight on the asker's "accept". It's already marked with a big, green check and displayed at the top in the default view. I don't see any reason for any other benefit.